# Jquery Ajax Fail to call web service

Tags: jquery, ajax

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) 
System.InvalidOperationException: InsertData Web Service method name is not valid.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)**

---

```
## `Heading` # <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
            var list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
            var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ list: list });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "WebService.asmx/InsertData",
                data: "{'FirstName':'" + $('#txtFirstName').val() + "','LastName':'" + $('#txtLastName').val() + "','City':'" + $('#txtCity').val() + "','EmailID':'" + $('#txtEmailID').val() + "'}",
                success: function (response) {
                    var obj = response.d;
                    if (obj == 'true') {
                        $('#txtproductname').val('');
                        $('#txtdescription').val('');
                        $('#txtdate').val('');
                        $('#txtprice').val('');
                        $('#lblmsg').html('Data Inserted Successfully');
                    }
                },
                failure: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>#
public static string InsertData(string EngPName, string EnDesc, string Mimage, string Drivers)
{
    string retMessage = string.Empty;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        string Query = "insert into Products(EngPName, EnDesc, Mimage,Drivers) values(@EngPName,@EnDesc,@Mimage,@Drivers)";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EngPName", EngPName);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EnDesc", EnDesc);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mimage", Mimage);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Drivers", Drivers);
            int AffectedRow = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (AffectedRow == 1)
            {
                retMessage = "true";
            }
            else
            {
                retMessage = "false";
            }
        }
        return retMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's telling you InsertData isn't a valid method name.  Your server side code will be more interesting for solving this problem.

Comment: Dont just paste your code along with an error message...give some context, previous attempts, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error (500) typically indicates that the called method is unable to interpret the passed data. The data property of the ajax call seems invalid. Try using this instead:

```
var data = {"firstName": $("#txtFirstName").val(), "lastName": $("#txtLastName").val(), "City": $("#txtCity").val(), "EmailID": $("#txtEmailID").val()};

$.ajax({
...

data: JSON.stringify(data),

...
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93dpnsvz/1/)